# Count of opportunities in account using process builder

Tags: community

How to display the count of opportunities in Account using only process builder, without use of roll up summary, triggers or flows?

Comment: For "display the count of opportunities" do you mean in a field?

Comment: Yes. 
I am new to salesforce. I was asked to display the count of opportunities in a field using only process builder. Is it possible?

Comment: I think that's not possible. the best way is to use the roll up fields and in case use these fields for your logic.

Comment: I am being informed that there is a way using one of the action types.

Comment: Yes, there is. but only if you use Apex Actions or flow, just like this post: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000p4xnQAA. Unfortunately Processes can't count the number of records or loop through lists. you need to use also the flows or the code to do this

Comment: You should first consider the free [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries tool](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) or the paid Rolliup Helper tool.